# SQL Server 2008 insert records then update fields based on another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In my searches I have found many threads that deal with my issue in round about ways but I have not been able to find one answer that clearly defines the answer.

Yes I'm a noob to SQL Server.

Here is what I am trying to do And I need to know the best way to do it. For the purposes of this question I will keep it simple. Remember it is the functionality I want

I have table A

```
ClientName,
manager name,
Location
```

Table B

```
Manager name
Manager location
```

Table C

```
Random columns,
Client name,
Manager name
```

I want to

- take the rows returned from `SELECT [client name], [manager name] from table c`
- Insert those rows into `table a` with `@clientname` and `@manager` name parameters already defined.

Once the row is inserted it will make

```
tableA.location = Select [manager location] 
                  from tableb  
                  where @manager = tableb.[manager name]
```

These needs to happen in a batch for multiple rows in one call

This is point in time data so no lookups and no blanket update queries

Use functions?

Stored procedures?

Triggers may not be the answer since I will be inputting 500+ rows on each call

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to believe you could not find something very closely related to your question. All you should have to do is

```
insert TableA
select C.ClientName, C.ManagerName, B.Location
from TableC C
join TableB B on B.ManagerName = C.ManagerName
where C.ManagerName = @ManagerName and C.ClientName = @clientname
```

Your stated usage case makes this look like you should wrap this inside of a stored proc. In fact, the statement above is the entire body of a stored proc

```
create proc sotest(@clientname varchar(40), @managername varchar(40)) as
begin
-- code above
end
```

It is not possible to avoid lookup of location from TableB as your have defined the problem (assuming you want to populated the Location column)

Comment: Hmmm the issue i am having is actually joining the tables. Later on tableb will change and that change does not need to iterate through tableA. So i need the value of location in table a to be static and needs to be updated on insert of the item

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you do as I described, location in TableA will be static (only set when it is inserted). Changing location in TableB will only affect items that are subsequently inserted.